# Getting uWebSockets for Visual 2017 via Conan

Tags: c++, visual-studio, conan, uwebsockets

I'm trying to add uWebSockets as a dependency in my conan.txt

`conan install ..` returns the following error:

```
ERROR: uwebsockets/18.3.0: Invalid configuration: uwebsockets requires a compiler that supports at least C++17
```

How can I handle this ?

- The error comes from https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/uwebsockets/all/conanfile.py
- I do have 15.9 : `** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.25`
- Adding a print() in the recipe show that **conan thinks I have version 15** (expanded to 15.0.0)
- Passing `-s compiler.version=15.9` returns an "invalid" error
- Reducing the minimal version to 15 in the recipe works, but clearly it's a hack, v15.0 did not support C++17, so this requirement is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Conan [settings](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/config_files/settings.yml.html) supports Visual Studio versions as integer numbers only.

> Passing -s compiler.version=15.9 returns an "invalid" error

It complains because your custom version, it is not listed in `settings.yml`, however you can add your version there, there is section explaining [how to customize your settings](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/custom_settings.html).

You just need to update your `settings.yml`, adding `15.9` to Visual Studio version list and it should work.

You could update your default [profile](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/profiles.html), or create a new one, based on that Visual Studio version.

Besides that, `15.9` is not `15`, therefore, you will need to build all dependencies from sources, due the incompatible package ID. You can make them compatible, but you will need to change the recipe locally and build again. Read  [compatible compilers](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/define_abi_compatibility.html#compatible-compilers) section for more information.

Comment: I though of that, and it works, thanks... Just seemed just as hackish (everyone in the team needs to manually edit this file ?!) . Now, the pre-built package doesn't exist in the public repo, and --build=missing fails, but that's another story

Comment: libuv/1.38.0: Calling build()
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio UnknownVersion 15.9 Win64 ... So yeah, adding a custom version seems a bit too violent.

Comment: > everyone in the team needs to manually edit this file ?!
NO! Read: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/config.html#conan-config-install

Comment: > CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio UnknownVersion 15.9 Win64.

That error is because Conan passes the VS version to CMake, which only supports major versions. The correct way to fix it, is fixing the recipe.

Comment: Please, follow https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/pull/3425 for the correct hotfix.

Comment: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/pull/8257 has been merged, will be released in Conan 1.33, and will output the right CMake generator for Visual versions including the minor too.